# How do i get the return_url after payment approval so i can get the Payer ID within return_url?

Tags: python-3.x, paypal, payment-gateway, paypal-rest-sdk

To execute the payment I need to Payment ID and Payer ID. Now I have the Payment ID which I get it from the create payment call. But the Payer ID isn't included inside. I understand that one can obtain the Payer ID from the return_url after payment approval. So how do I get that return_url / Payer ID?

I have tried looking at the docs at paypal website and it is written "# Execute payment with the payer ID from the create payment call (following redirect)". This is the part I cant get.

```
class PayPal():
    paypalrestsdk.configure({
        "mode": "sandbox", # sandbox or live
        "client_id": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
        "client_secret": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" })

    def create_payment(self):
        payment = paypalrestsdk.Payment({
            "intent": "sale",
            "payer": {
                "payment_method": "paypal"},
            "redirect_urls": {
                "return_url": "http://www.example.com",
                "cancel_url": "http://www.example.com"},
            "transactions": [{
                "item_list": {
                    "items": [{
                        "name": "item",
                        "sku": "pcs",
                        "price": "5.00",
                        "currency": "USD",
                        "quantity": 1}]},
                "amount": {
                    "total": "5.00",
                    "currency": "USD"},
                "description": "This is the payment transaction description."}]})

        if payment.create():
            # Extract redirect url
            for link in payment.links:
                if link.method == "REDIRECT":
                    # Capture redirect url
                    redirect_url = (link.href)
                    webbrowser.open("%s"% (redirect_url))
                    print(link)
            print("Payment created successfully")
            print (payment)
        else:
            print("Error while creating payment:")

            print(payment.error)
    def execute_payment(self):
        payment = paypalrestsdk.Payment.find("%s" % payment.id)
        if payment.execute({"payer_id": "%s" % payment.payerid}):
            print("Payment[%s] execute successfully" % (payment.id))
        else:
            print(payment.error)
```

This is what I get in the create payment call:

{'intent': 'sale', 'payer': {'payment_method': 'paypal'}, 'redirect_urls': {'return_url': 'http://www.example.com', 'cancel_url': 'http://www.example.com'}, 'transactions': [{'amount': {'total': '5.00', 'currency': 'USD'}, 'description': 'This is the payment transaction description.', 'item_list': {'items': [{'name': 'item', 'sku': 'pcs', 'price': '5.00', 'currency': 'USD', 'quantity': 1}]}, 'related_resources': []}], 'id': 'PAYID-xxxxxxxxxxxxxx', 'state': 'created', 'create_time': '2019-05-12T06:37:19Z', 'links': [{'href': 'https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAYID-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', 'rel': 'self', 'method': 'GET'}, {'href': 'https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=EC-xxxxxxxxxxxxx', 'rel': 'approval_url', 'method': 'REDIRECT'}, {'href': 'https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAYID-xxxxxxxxxxxx/execute', 'rel': 'execute', 'method': 'POST'}]}